# How do I find the path to the fonts on my server?

Tags: centos

I am writing a PHP script which needs to use True Type Fonts as the default ones bundled with the GD library aren't really useful in a professional application. In order to specify which font I intend to use I must specify the full path to the font. Unfortunately I am unsure what that is.

How do I find the path to the fonts on my server?

My server is CentOS 4.8 running cPanel.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try `'rpm -qa | grep font'` (from a terminal window - I'm pretty sure cpanel has that feature). It will output a couple packages that have font in the name.

Then from that output use (you can try for each package):

```
rpm -ql somepackage-font
```

To list all the files/directoires associated with that font package - this should list all the font directories. Hope this helps.